# jQuery Plug-in to handle translation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, machine-translation

I recently have come across with a need for some type of "translation"-type plug-in that could translate specific fields or areas to other languages.

I am not sure if something like this even is out there - but I thought this might be a good place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [Sunday Morning jQuery plug-in](http://sundaymorning.jaysalvat.com/). It utilizes the [Google Translate API](http://code.google.com/apis/language/) and can translate either single words (perhaps on a click event), entire fields, or whatever else you might need to do.

**Example of usage:** (*Double clicking a word for French translation*)

**HTML**

```
<div id="example2">     
     <p class="example">My kingdom for a horse!</p>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#example2 .example').sundayMorningReset();           
  $('#example2 .example').sundayMorningBubble({
       source:'en',
       destination:'fr'
  });
```

Take a look through their documentation near the bottom of the page - as it features all the different methods of implementing it, hope this helps.

Comment: Added an example in there so you could more easily see how it is used - If you need anything else, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks Rionmonster - this is EXACTLY what I have been searching for!